# How to hyperlink to section title frame

Tags: beamer, hyperref

I am using the mtheme for LaTeX Beamer.
This theme inserts a title frame with the section title at the beginning of each section.

```
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begingroup
  \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{parent=palette primary}
  \begin{frame}[plain]
    \vspace{2em}\usebeamerfont{section title}
    \progressbar@sectionprogressbar%
  \end{frame}
  \endgroup
}
```

How can I hyperlink to this frame? Labeling the section is obviously not sufficient to be able to link to this frame.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Luckily beamer provides a command for this: `\hyperlinksectionstart{text}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSection{
  \begin{frame}[plain]
        \insertsection
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

    \section{sec1}
    \frame{test \hyperlinksectionstart{start of section} }

    \section{sec2}
    \frame{test \hyperlinksectionstart{start of section} }

\end{document}
```